# Rational PurifyPlus: where to buy? Any experience with alternatives?

Tags: windows-7, purify, rational-purify

I have been looking on the webs for a possibility to purchase **Rational PurifyPlus** for Windows.
In our company, we have been using Purify in the past and want to replace it with licenses for the current version because we need to support Windows 7.

The Rational Software division was sold by **IBM** to **UNICOM Systems** in late 2014. Until the present day, I have been unable to find any place or store that would offer to sell a license. There's not even a "how to buy" section on UNICOM's website!

Attempts to gain information by using the company's contact form remained unanswered.

If you were able to purchase that product within the last year, it would be somewhat helpful if you could share with me how you achieved this.

Alternatively, can somebody elaborate on a suitable alternative to Purify?
Maybe you recently ditched Purify for something else and are happier than before?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that directly contacting the company and asking for a quotation finally led to a result.

Future readers: **UNICOM** does not appear to attach great value to the smaller client audiences (small business or single developers): There is a minimum number of licenses a customer is required to purchase.

Comment: too bad, we are holding 8 PurifyPlus licenses. No more support/update going fwd.. Do we have any good replacement for PurifyPlus?

Comment: IBM was bad enough!  It seems every time Purify got sold, or its owner taken over, it got harder to buy, and he support got worse.